# IORegistryEntry::fromPath() fail

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, iokit

my IOKit kext is failing *on older iMacs* to locate the /options path in the DeviceTree plane of the IORegistry.  has anybody else encountered this or know why it would fail?
thx->adv

```
  IORegistryEntry* regEntry = IORegistryEntry::fromPath("/options", gIODTPlane);
  if(NULL == regEntry)
  {
    regEntry = IORegistryEntry::fromPath("IODeviceTree:/options");  
    if(NULL == regEntry)
    {
      DEBUG_LOG("getIORegOptionsEntry: FAILURE TO LOCATE: IODeviceTree:/options\n");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path used to create IORegistryEntry is invalid as [per the API](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/IORegistryEntry_h/Classes/IORegistryEntry/index.html#//apple_ref/cpp/clm/IORegistryEntry/fromPath/IORegistryEntry*/(constchar*,constIORegistryPlane*,char*,int*,IORegistryEntry*)): it should begins with a ':'. The I/O plane should not be included in the path, but as the second parameter.